# how to submit highlighted text from textarea into database

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have to save highlighted text from textarea into database on click event
how can i do it. I found some code from so but it doesn't work for me.

```js
$('#send').on("click", function(){
 ShowSelection();
});

function ShowSelection()
 {
  var textComponent = $('#my-content span').val();
  console.log(textComponent);
  var selectedText;

  if (textComponent.selectionStart !== undefined)
  {// Standards Compliant Version
   var startPos = textComponent.selectionStart;
   var endPos = textComponent.selectionEnd;
   selectedText = textComponent.value.substring(startPos, endPos);
  }
  else if (document.selection !== undefined)
  {// IE Version
   textComponent.focus();
   var sel = document.selection.createRange();
   selectedText = sel.text;
  }
  alert("You selected: " + selectedText);
 }
```

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5379120/get-the-highlighted-selected-text

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot wrong with your code:

`selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` are properties of form elements (input, textarea), but `$('#my-content span')` is obviously finding a `<span>` element.

`$('#my-content span').val()` will return a string (in the case of an input it's the value of that input, but in your case it will be empty, because you apply it on a span element.

`textComponent.selectionStart`: Since `textComponent` is a string and not an HTML element there is no property `selectionStart` on `textComponent`.

--

Working example for a `<textarea>`element ([see here](http://help.dottoro.com/ljtfkhio.php)):

```
    var startPos = $('textarea')[0].selectionStart
    // etc.
```

Working example for `<span>`element ([see here](http://help.dottoro.com/ljfjepre.php)):

```
    var selectedText = window.getSelection().toString()
```